# How to sort Vector by value in SparkML?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I get some Feature Vector using tf-idf algorithm in SparkML. Now I want to get the max value in each Vector. How to sort the Vector by value or get the max value of it?

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
val testDF = spark.read.json("/dataset/yelp_review_test.json")
val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("words")
val wordsData = tokenizer.transform(testDF)
//wordsData.show()
val hashTF = new HashingTF().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("tfFeatures")
val tfFeatures = hashTF.transform(wordsData)
//tfFeatures.select("review_id","words","tfFeatures").foreach(println(_))
val idf = new IDF().setInputCol("tfFeatures").setOutputCol("idfFeatures")

val idfModel = idf.fit(tfFeatures)
val allDF = idfModel.transform(tfFeatures)
allDF.show()
```

[image]

A row Vector of idfFeatures is like this:

```
(262144,[7617,24417,36200,61231,65069,66865,95805,103838,117481,138356,142373,151536,161061,189683,200556,204852,205044,218917,222453,227410,232735,235447],[2.1972245773362196,0.1823215567939546,1.5040773967762742,0.49247648509779424,1.791759469228055,1.2809338454620642,1.2809338454620642,0.0,1.791759469228055,1.0986122886681098,2.1972245773362196,0.8109302162163288,2.1972245773362196,0.25131442828090617,2.1972245773362196,2.1972245773362196,0.4054651081081644,1.791759469228055,1.888923217681703,0.0,2.1972245773362196,2.1972245773362196])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a sparkML vector, you can convert it to a normal collection and use the available functions to find the max like this:

```
myVector.toArray.reduce( (a, b) => if (a > b) a else b )
```

Or to replace the vector in your tuple:

```
df.map( (myInt, myIntList, myVecList) => (myInt, myVec.toArray.reduce( (a, b) => if (a > b) a else b ) ) )
```

Comment: It is a org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector. How to get the max value?

Comment: Instead of simply calling `myVector.reduce` you can call `myVector.toArray.reduce`. I have edited the answer, is that more clear?

Comment: But Vector can't use ">" to compare. Vector's format is [Int,[Int],[Double]]. I want to get the max double value.

Comment: We are comparing the `Double` values there. `Vector.toArray` returns `double[]`. The first component of my answer simply shows how to find max from a `Vector`. The second component should show how to extract that array from your tuple.

Comment: allDF.select("idfFeatures").rdd.map { case Row(v: Vector) => v} is ok, but allDF.select("idfFeatures").rdd.map{case Row(myInt:Int, myIntList:Array[Int], myVecList:Array[Double]) => myVecList.toArray.reduce( (a, b) => if (a > b) a else b  )} will print scala.MatchError.

Comment: I use vectors.first().foreachActive((a,b) => map += (a -> b)) to get the value. It works.

Comment: May I suggest `udf((v: Vector) => v.toSparse.values.max)` sir?

Comment: Very useful! @LostInOverflow